# Is it possible to programmatically scroll a WPF ListView so that a desired grouping header is placed at its top?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-listview

Given a `ListView` bound to items that have been grouped using a `PropertyGroupDescription`, is it possible to programmatically scroll so that a group is placed at the top of the list? I am aware that I can scroll to the first item in the group, since that item belongs to the collection the `ListView` is bound to. However, I have not been able to find any resources describing how to scroll to a group header (styled with a `GroupStyle`).

To give an example of the desired functionality, let's look at the settings page in *Visual Studio Code*. This page consists of a panel that allows the user to scroll through all of the application's settings (organized under their respective groups) as well as a tree structure on the left for faster navigation to a specific group in the main panel. In the screenshot attached, I clicked the **Formatting** option in the tree on the left, and the main panel automatically scrolled so that the corresponding group header was place at the top of the main panel.

How can this be recreated in WPF (if at all possible)? Could the "infinite" scrolling of the main settings panel in *Visual Studio Code* be mimicked with another WPF control?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree on the left (the TOC) has root nodes (the sections e.g. 'TextEditor'). Each section holds categories of settings (e.g. 'Formatting'). The `ListView` on the right (settings view) has items that have a group header with category names that match those of the TOC (e.g. Formatting).

### 1. Edit to address the use of [`PropertyGroupDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.propertygroupdescription?view=netframework-4.8)

Assumptions:

- there exists a `CollectionViewSource` defined inside a
  `ResourceDictionary` and named *CollectionViewSource*.
- The settings data items have a property `SettingsCategoryName` (e.g. Formatting).
- The `SettingsCategoryName` of the `SelectedItem` of the
  `TreeView` is bound to a property `SelectedSettingsCategoryName`

View.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionViewSource" Source="{Binding Settings}">
      <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="SettingsCategoryName"/>
      </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
  </CollectionViewSource>
</ResourceDictionary>

<ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSource}}">
  <ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                     FontSize="14"
                     Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
  </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

View.xaml.cs:
Find the selected category and scroll it to the top of the viewport.

```
// Scroll the selected section to top when the selected item has changed
private void ScrollToSection()
{
  CollectionViewSource viewSource = FindResource("CollectionViewSource") as CollectionViewSource;
  CollectionViewGroup selectedGroupItemData = viewSource
    .View
    .Groups
    .OfType<CollectionViewGroup>()
    .FirstOrDefault(group => group.Name.Equals(this.SelectedSettingsCategoryName));

  GroupItem selectedroupItemContainer = this.ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedGroupItemData) as GroupItem;

  ScrollViewer scrollViewer;
  if (!TryFindCildElement(this.ListView, out scrollViewer))
  {
    return;
  }

  // Subscribe to scrollChanged event 
  // because the scroll executed by `BringIntoView` is deferred.
  scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += ScrollSelectedGroupToTop;

  selectedGroupItemContainer?.BringIntoView();
}

private void ScrollSelectedGroupToTop(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ScrollViewer scrollViewer;
  if (!TryFindCildElement(this.ListView, out scrollViewer))
  {
    return;
  }

  scrollViewer.ScrollChanged -= ScrollGroupToTop;
  var viewSource = FindResource("CollectionViewSource") as CollectionViewSource;

  CollectionViewGroup selectedGroupItemData = viewSource
    .View
    .Groups
    .OfType<CollectionViewGroup>()
    .FirstOrDefault(group => group.Name.Equals(this.SelectedSettingsCategoryName));

  var groupIndex = viewSource
    .View
    .Groups.IndexOf(selectedGroupItemData);

  var absoluteVerticalScrollOffset = viewSource
    .View
    .Groups
    .OfType<CollectionViewGroup>()
    .TakeWhile((group, index) => index < groupIndex)
    .Sum(group =>
      (this.ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(group) as GroupItem)?.ActualHeight 
     ?? 0
    );

  scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(absoluteVerticalScrollOffset);
}

// Generic method to find any `DependencyObject` in the visual tree of a parent element
private bool TryFindCildElement<TElement>(DependencyObject parent, out TElement resultElement) where TElement : DependencyObject
{
  resultElement = null;
  for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
  {
    DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);

    if (childElement is Popup popup)
    {
      childElement = popup.Child;
    }

    if (childElement is TElement)
    {
      resultElement = childElement as TElement;
      return true;
    }

    if (TryFindCildElement(childElement, out resultElement))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

You can move this method into a `ListView` derived type. Then add a `CommandBindings` to the new custom `ListView` that handles a Routed Command e.g. `ScrollToSectionRoutedCommand`. Template the `TreeViewItems` to be a `Button` and let them emit the command to pass the section name as `CommandParameter` to the custom `ListView`.

**Remarks**
Since the use of `PropertyGroupDescription` results in an items source of mixed data types (`GroupItemData` for the group headers and in addition the actual data items) the UI virtualization of the hosting `ItemsControl` is disabled and not possible (see Microsoft Docs: 
[Optimizing performance: Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls#displaying-large-data-sets)). In this scenario the attached property `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` is automatically set to `False` (forced). For big list this can be a huge drawback and a reason to follow an alternative approach.

### 2. Alternative solution (with UI virtualization support)

There are several possible variations when it comes to the design of the actual settings structure. It can be a tree where each category header node has its own child nodes which represent settings of a category or a flat list structure where category headers and settings are all siblings. For the sake of the example's simplicity I choose the second option: a flat list data structure.

### 2.1 The setup

**Basic idea:**
the `TreeView` is templated using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` with two levels. The second level of the `TreeView` (leafs) and `ListView` share the same instances of the header items (`IHeaederData`. See later). Therefore the selected header item of the `TreeView` references the *exact same* item header in the `ListView` - no search required.

**Implementation overview:**

- You need two `ItemsControl` elements:

  - one `TreeView` for the navigation pane on the left with two levels

    - with a section root node (e.g. 'Text Editor')
    - and the settings category header child nodes (leaf nodes) of that section (e.g. 'Font', 'Formatting')
  - one `ListView` for the actual settings and their category headers.
- Then design the data types to represent a setting, a settings header and a section root node

  - Let them all implement a common `IData` with shared attributes (e.g. a header)
  - Let the settings header data type implement an additional
    `IHeaderData`
  - Let the settings data type implement an additional `ISettingData`
  - Let the parent section node data type (root node) for the `TreeView` implement an additional `ISectionData` which has children of type `IHeaderData`
- Create the item source collections (all of type `IEnumerable<IData>`)

  - one for each parent section node of the `TreeView` (which holds the categories only), a `SectionCollection` of type `ISectionData`
  - one for each of the categories, a `CategoryCollection` of type `IHeaderData`
  - a single one for the settings data and the shared categories (the header data), a `SettingCollection` of type `IData`
- populate the sorted source collections section by section

  - add a section data instance of type `ISectionData` to the source collection `SectionCollection` of the `TreeView`
  - add a shared category data header instance of type `IHeaderData` to both source collections `CategoryCollection` and `SettingCollection`
  - add a settings instances of type `ISettingData`, one for each setting of the category, to the `SettingCollection` only
  - repeat the last two steps for all categories of the current  section
  - assign the `CategoryCollection` to the child collection of the `ISectionData` root node
  - repeat the steps for all sections (with its categories and the corresponding settings)
- Bind the `SectionCollection` to the  `TreeView`
- Bind the `SettingsCollection` to the `LIstView`
- Create a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the `TreeView` data where `ISectionData` type is the root
- Create two `DataTemplate` for the `ListView`

  - one that targets `IHeaderData`
  - one that targets `ISettingData`

The logic:

- When a `IHeaderData` item of the `TreeView` is selected then

  - get the `ListView` item container of this data item using `var container = ItemsContainerGenerator.GetContainerFromItem(selectedTreeViewCategoryItem)`
  - Scroll the container into view `container.BringIntoView()` (to realize virtualized items that are out of view)
  - Scroll the container to the top of the view

Because `TreeView` and `ListView` share the same category header data (`IHeaderData`) the selected items are easy to track and to find. You don't have to search the group of settings. You can directly jump to the group using the reference. 
This means the structure of the data is the key of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you saying that this functionality can only be achieved when the 'headers' in the `ListView` are really just another item in the list, as opposed to groups formed from `PropertyGroupDescription`? I was able to follow your logic to code up the desired functionality, though I think it's worth pointing out that this solution only mimics grouping. For my use case, this is acceptable, though I'm still curious whether this can be achieved when using `PropertyGroupDescription`. (I'll accept this as the answer if nobody provides any other feedback). Thanks again!

Comment: You don't _have to_ share the header items. This is just for faster lookup as you can scroll to the item group using the reference. That's super fast. If you you don't do this you have to _search_ the item.  It's not mimicking. It's effectively grouping. But if you use `PropertyGroupDescription` you are more flexible to create groups even dynamically. But for your scenario you wouldn't need this as the grouping is fix. If you need dynamic groups then you can consider using `PropertyGroupDescription` and sacrifice fast lookup or you manually create a fixed grouping but have fast lookup.

Comment: You can use a better population algorithm. This was just to describe the structure better. For more dynamic templating I suggest to introduce more interfaces for the settings that all should extend `ISettingsData`. Let them all have a `Description` attribute. According to the classification a special `DataTemplate` will apply: `ITextSetting` (which will have a `TextBox`), `IBooleanSetting` (will have a `CheckBox` or `ToggleButton`), `ISingleOptionsSetting` (will have `RadioButton` selectors), `IMultioptionsSetting` (will have a `ComboBox`), `IColorSetting` (will have a ` ColorPalette`), etc.

Comment: Initially I was using `PropertyGroupDescription`, but I was not able to figure out how to scroll the `ListView` to the group headers, which is what prompted this question. Do you have an idea of how that can be accomplished? I'm satisfied with the solution you've provided, but it would be nice to settle whether this can be achieved with `PropertyGroupDescription`.

Comment: You would need to iterate over the source collection. The idea is that `PropertyGroupDescription` uses a specified property to group the items. Let's say this property is called `SettingsCategory` and items of the same group share the same value. All you need to do is to find the first item (smallest index) that matches the `SettingsCategory` value of the clicked `TreeView` item. Then follow the _The logic_ section of my answer: get the container, bring it into view and then scroll it to the top.

Comment: A second approach is to get the `CollectionViewSource` of t he `ListView`. This view source will contain items of type ` CollectionViewGroup`. Use ` CollectionViewGroup.Name` to identify the group as the `Name` is the name of the property that is used as grouping constraint. Once you identified the right ` CollectionViewGroup` use `CollectionViewGroup.Items.FirstOrDefault()` to get the first item of this group. Refer to the section _The logic_  of my answer to bring it into view.

Comment: @estebro I updated the answer to address your request to show how this can be achieved using `PropertyGroupDescription`.

Comment: Your latest edit is exactly the code I had when I first posted this question, and I believe your `ScrollToSection` function is what I was missing. One last question. Do you know why `BringIntoView` sometimes does not actually bring the group header into view? I imagine this has to do with the current position of the viewer when the function is called, but I have tried to call `ScrollToBottom` prior to `BringIntoView` and yet the header is not always placed at the top.

Comment: `BringIntoView()` only forces to create the item container in case of UI virtualization. It then scrolls the container into the viewport. I think it had something to do with your initial scroller position. If you are positioned before the target item that you want to bring into view than it brings the item to the top of the viewport. If you are behind the item you wish to scroll it will be scrolled to the bottom of the viewport. As soon it is in the viewport the positioning is completed. That's why I added "Scroll to top" as the next step after calling `BringIntoView()`.

Comment: That is what I was trying to address in my previous comment, where I mentioned that I attempted to scroll the group header to the top by doing a `ScrollToBottom` prior to calling `BringIntoView`. If I understand correctly, that should have positioned the viewer after the desired item, thus scrolling it to the top after I call `BringIntoView`. Is that logic not correct? Because it did not have the desired results in my case.

Comment: No. Step one: bring into view (realize item in case virtualization is enabled and the desired item is virtualized). Then Scroll this item to top explicitly. I show you how to do it. Wait...

Comment: @estebro I updated the answer to provide an example that shows how to scroll the selected group to top. You have to explicitly position the `ScrollViewer`. Everything else is not reliable.

Comment: I was afraid that accomplishing this with the PropertyGroups was not going to be very straightforward. I have implemented this, and I cannot help but feel like your idea of adding both the settings and the group headers to the list and templating them differently is a more elegant solution. You might want to edit your answer one last time to suggest that alternative for anyone who prefers a simpler approach. Either way, I am accepting this solution, since it now answers the original question. Thank you so much for all your help and constant feedback.

Comment: @estebro Thank you. I put back my first and recommended solution. I also added a remark to the approach using the `PropertyGroupDescription`. Long story short: `PropertyGroupDescription` disables UI virtualization. This can lead to noticeable performance issues for bigger lists. That's why I don't recommend the use of `PropertyGroupDescription` if it can be avoided. The other approach I came up with allows for UI virtualization as long as you follow the recommendation to let all data items implement the common `IData` interface and use an items source of type  `IEnumerable<IData>`.

Comment: Yes, I've implemented both methods and I definitely see a performance difference (in favor of the approach without `PropertyGroupDescription`). I think your response now both answers the original question and provides a better alternative. Thank you again.